# In Objective-C/Cocoa, are there global events for when mission control is activated or spaces are changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events, nsstatusitem, nspopover

I'm currently working on an OSX menubar app that uses a custom status item view and a NSPopover to display content.

I'm trying to get it to dismiss at times that would make sense like when spaces are changed, since the popover doesn't move spaces like a window does, or when mission controller is activated.

Currently, when in mission control, the NSPopover stays on top as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9cm9.jpg).

Currently I'm using `NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:` with some mouse event masks and that works alright but doesn't cover all needed events.

So, is there a way to detect when major OS events happen like opening mission control, changing spaces etc?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried using NSPopoverBehaviorTransient but I lost some needed control when the popup closes. Just adding that bit on info for completion sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get notified of space changes by registering for `NSWorkspace`'s `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification`. There isn't a notification as such for Mission Control, but you might investigate whether `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` or other notifications can be used to determine what you need.

HTH

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help! `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification` Worked perfectly for space changes! So far I haven't been able to find anything for Mission Control but I'm getting close to the point of abandoning NSPopover for a panel or window instead.